# Mod rewrite put entire REQUEST_URI into GET request

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to pass the entire Request_Uri into a $_GET request however the only things it's passing is 'test.php'

```
Htaccess code
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php?data=$1 [L]

test.php
<?php
echo $_GET['data'];
?>
```

However the only thing it display is 'test.php' what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# skips files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# skips directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php?data=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Without these 2 conditions your rules runs twice since you're matching `.*` and you get rewritten URI `test.php` as `GET` parameter.

Comment: Done, had to wait 10 minutes. Thanks again